# Cannot see server.xml

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I have created a Liberty project in eclipse mars and pushed it to Bluemix server. Upon opening the Application Files and Logs and going to `app -> .liberty -> usr -> server`, I cannot see defaultserver folder or `server.xml` file. I have also tried to bind services but without any success. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the liberty server and is server.xml is located in the application 'Files and Logs' section under `app -> wlp -> usr -> servers`. This folder should contain the defaultServer (or your own server name if you pushed a liberty server).

Answer (score 1):

You should also try the following command from the cf cli to list the deployed app file structure:

```
 cf files APP_NAME
```

[image: Shows cf Files APP_NAME command usage]

You could also use the following command to list the detailed folder content:

```
 cf files APP_NAME [PATH]
```

[image: Shows cf Files APP_NAME PATH command usage]